# How to generate simple visio file?

Tags: visio

I need to create a program that creates Visio compatible file based on the provided data but i'm really lost at where to start.
I just need to draw simpe things like lines, images and text.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use (automate) Visio itself to draw the stuff. This assumes that you'll have Visio installed on the computer where your program will run.
Check out Visio SDK, it has many examples to start with.

Second, there is for example aspose.diagrams library (commercial) which can do that without Visio installed.

Third, with new Visio 2013 vsdx (open XML) you can use OpenXML SDK, to generate the drawing, and do the heavy lifting yourself.